# azkaban install gradlew specify java location

Tags: java, gradlew, azkaban

environment:CentOS 8.1 64bit,azkaban 3.90.0 ,java 14.0.1

```
sudo adduser azkaban
cd /home/azkaban
git clone git@github.com:azkaban/azkaban.git
git checkout tags/3.90.0 -b 3.90.0-branch
```

when I run

```
cd /home/azkaban/azkaban
./gradlew clean build
```

it says

```
Could not determine java version from '14.0.1'.
```

and in file /home/azkaban/azkaban/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:  
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

so I decide to use lower java version, I have put jdk 11 in /opt/jdk-11

```
# /opt/jdk-11/bin/java --version
openjdk 11 2018-09-25
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)
```

,so I run

```
./gradlew clean build -Dorg.gradle.java.home=/opt/jdk-11/
```

it still say

```
Could not determine java version from '14.0.1'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I change to JDK1.8,and it begin to build,